# not able to push to heroku issue with gyp

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

i am getting this err when i am trying to push to heruko:
i tried to set the node version in package.json file and set it to  "node": "10.x", but still doesn't seem to work.
please note that it was working perfectly before and i pushed to heruko multiple times but after I changed npm version using nvm I couldn't push to heruko anymore.

```
     > grpc@1.10.1 install /tmp/build_fe6c53d3de190b8e66ab937494b777cc/node_modules/grpc
remote:        > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library
remote:
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download(403): https://storage.googleapis.com/grpc-precompiled-binaries/node/grpc/v1.10.1/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc.tar.gz
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for grpc@1.10.1 and node@12.9.0 (node-v72 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.10.1 and node@12.9.0 (node-v72 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! Hit error Connection closed while downloading tarball file
remote:        make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_fe6c53d3de190b8e66ab937494b777cc/node_modules/grpc/build'
remote:        make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_fe6c53d3de190b8e66ab937494b777cc/node_modules/grpc/build'
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o
remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/avl/avl.o
remote:        sed: can't read ./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o.d.raw: No such file or directory
remote:        rm: cannot remove './Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o.d.raw': No such file or directory
remote:        grpc.target.mk:402: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o' failed
remote:        make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/surface/init.o] Error 1
remote:        make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_fe6c53d3de190b8e66ab937494b777cc/node_modules/grpc/build'
remote:        gyp ERR! build error
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_fe6c53d3de190b8e66ab937494b777cc/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:196:23)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1062-aws
remote:        gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_fe6c53d3de190b8e66ab937494b777cc/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_fe6c53d3de190b8e66ab937494b777cc/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=/tmp/build_fe6c53d3de190b8e66ab937494b777cc/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc/grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=/tmp/build_fe6c53d3de190b8e66ab937494b777cc/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/node-v72-linux-x64-glibc"
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_fe6c53d3de190b8e66ab937494b777cc/node_modules/grpc
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v12.9.0
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
remote:        node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute ore/lib/channel/channel_args.o
remote:        cc1plus: fatal error: ../deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.cc: No such file or directory
remote:        compilation terminated.
remote:        grpc.target.mk:402: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.o' failed
remote:        make: *** [Release/obj.target/grpc/deps/grpc/src/core/lib/channel/channel_args.o] Error 1
remote:        make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_fe6c53d3de190b8e66ab937494b777cc/node_modules/grpc/build'
remote:        gyp ERR! build error
remote:        gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_fe6c53d3de190b8e66ab937494b777cc/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:196:23)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:209:13)
remote:        gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
remote:        gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1062-aws
remote:        gyp ERR! command 
remote:        gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_fe6c53d3de190b8e66ab937494b777cc/node_modules/grpc
remote:        gyp ERR! node -v v12.9.0
remote:        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.3
remote:        gyp ERR! not ok
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! grpc@1.10.1 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.10.1 install script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.ovjxy/_logs/2020-04-12T11_53_14_105Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to expensify-react-akamal.
remote:
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```